# Trouble Binding Items to ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

The headers in my `ListView` display properly but the cells all display `Initialize.ListViewItemsData` instead of my test data.

`Initialize` is the class.

xaml code :

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewRoles" Margin="10,146,20,0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <!-- Heder -->
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Stato" Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Regola" Width="400"/>
                <GridViewColumn  Header="Risultato" Width="320"/>
                <!-- ListView Template-->
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumnName" Header="Name"  Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image x:Name="Image_GridViewColumnName" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding GridViewColumnName_ImageSource}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GridViewColumnName_LabelContent}" Width="400" Height="20"  />
                                <Label Content="{Binding GridViewColumnResult}"  />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

behind code:

```
public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> ListViewItemsCollections { get { return _ListViewItemsCollections; } }
    ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> _ListViewItemsCollections = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData>();

    public splashForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        idSearchLbl.Content = string.Empty;
        lblVersion.Content = "Versione : " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

        ListViewItemsCollections.Add(new ListViewItemsData()
        {
            GridViewColumnName_ImageSource = @"C:\Users\develop\TFS\CorridoioNew\FrontEnd\images\avi.png",
            GridViewColumnName_LabelContent = "abcdefghijk",
            GridViewColumnResult ="result ..... content"
        });

        listViewRoles.ItemsSource = ListViewItemsCollections;
    }
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: This is an unclear statement mate

Comment: Sorry for my bad language; Thanks Tone ; now work fine !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the xaml code you're looking for is

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewRoles" Margin="10,146,20,0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Stato" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image x:Name="Image_GridViewColumnName" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding GridViewColumnName_ImageSource}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Regola" Width="400">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GridViewColumnName_LabelContent}" Width="400" Height="20"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Risultato" Width="320">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding GridViewColumnResult}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

If you don't need to specify the text container types, you can specify the row height in ItemContainerStyle and simplify those bindings with

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewRoles" Margin="10,146,20,0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" >
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Stato" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image x:Name="Image_GridViewColumnName" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding GridViewColumnName_ImageSource}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Regola" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GridViewColumnName_LabelContent}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Risultato" Width="320" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GridViewColumnResult}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Your code behind works fine with both of these.

Comment: That's great. No problem!